# Meta query: How do I return posts within a date period from a given month?

Tags: search, meta-query, date

I have posts with a meta start_date and a meta end_date, stored in timestamp format (I can change the format if necessary)
I would like to return all posts that have a date in that month by giving a specific month.

For example, if I am looking for June 2019 and a post has a start_date from May 15, 2019 to June 3, 2019, this post should be returned.

How can I make this query?

Comment: OL, so intersection of post period and the month should not be empty? So the posts May 25th to July 15th and June 29th to July 2nd should also be found?

Comment: Perhaps you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32162166/1743124). Don't forget to mention the relation is `AND`.